# How to get Azure Search results that contains at least one complete word?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm testing the following query in Azure Search portal but is not giving me the expected results.
I want as result any document having at least one ocurrence of `algo` word.

> search=**algo**&queryType=full&searchMode=any

Important: `MyVal` is *Searchable* and have *Lucene Analyzer (spanish)*

Expected element result:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://....windows.net/indexes(....)/$metadata#docs(*)",
    "value": [
        {
            "MyKey":"1",
            "MyValues":[
                {
                    "MyVal":"algo aqui"
                },
                {
                    "MyVal":"lala"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

NOT expected element result:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://....windows.net/indexes(....)/$metadata#docs(*)",
    "value": [
        {
            "MyKey":"1",
            "MyValues":[
                {
                    "MyVal":"algoOtherStuff aqui"
                },
                {
                    "MyVal":"lala"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Result got:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://....windows.net/indexes(....)/$metadata#docs(*)",
    "value": []
}
```

**More example queries and results**

> search=**algo***&queryType=full&searchMode=any

[No results]

---

> search=/.*algo*./&queryType=full&searchMode=any

[No results]

---

> search=**algo aqui**&queryType=full&searchMode=any

[EXPECTED RESULT!!!] (element found)

---

> search=**aqui**&queryType=full&searchMode=any

[EXPECTED RESULT!!!] (element found)

---

**IMPORTANT:** If I change the words for two others to test like: "some data" or "something special" and search by one of those, Azure Search is returning the expected results. Seems like a problem with **"algo"** particular word.

Comment: Just to check you do have docs in your index and what shape results will take, can you do a search for "*"?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy sure, I'm able to find those documents with no filters search or by its own keys

Comment: OK, I don't see anything obviously wrong here, so I'd try maybe "some*" next to see if you still have results?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy It's weird, I changed to other words and don't have any problem. I posted not real words cause are in other language (spanish) but it seems that is something related to this specific phrase/word. I will update question with real words.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I've updated question with relevant info

Comment: it's still not clear what you want to achieve. you want to search by partial terms inside the complex fields?

Comment: try the following regex: /algo.*/

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio if I have a document with complex field with value "algo aqui" inside and I search by keyword "algo" I want to get this document as result. Is not a substring search, just checking word "algo" is present. The problem is that querying by "algo" don't return results. Also I guess is something particular with this word cause if I change the testing set all is fine. eg: searching by "something" I'm able to find document's having "something special" value. More clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was able to reproduce the problem with the following code:

```
var client = new SearchServiceClient("xxxx", new SearchCredentials("abcabc"));

            client.Indexes.Create(new Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.Index
            {
                Name = "index",
                Fields = new List<Field>
                {
                    new Field("Id", DataType.String){ IsKey = true, IsRetrievable = true, IsFilterable = true},
                    Field.NewComplex("MyValues", true, new List<Field> { new Field("MyVal", DataType.String)
                        {
                            IsRetrievable = true,
                            IsFilterable = true,
                            IsSearchable =true,
                            Analyzer = AnalyzerName.EsLucene
                        }
                    })
                }
            });

            var docs = new List<CustomDoc> {
                new CustomDoc { Id = "1", MyValues = new MyValues[] { new MyValues { MyVal = "algo aqui" }, new MyValues { MyVal = "lala" }} },
                new CustomDoc { Id = "2", MyValues = new MyValues[] { new MyValues { MyVal = "something else" }, new MyValues { MyVal = "xxx" }} },
            };

            var indexClient = client.Indexes.GetClient("index");
            indexClient.Documents.Index(IndexBatch.Upload(docs));
```

And yes, you were right. "Algo" is considered a stop word in the StandardLucene analyzer (spanish) :

https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/resources/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/spanish_stop.txt

Changing to EsMicrosoft analyzer returns searches for "algo":

```
client.Indexes.Create(new Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.Index
            {
                Name = "index",
                Fields = new List<Field>
                {
                    new Field("Id", DataType.String){ IsKey = true, IsRetrievable = true, IsFilterable = true},
                    Field.NewComplex("MyValues", true, new List<Field> { new Field("MyVal", DataType.String)
                        {
                            IsRetrievable = true,
                            IsFilterable = true,
                            IsSearchable =true,
                            Analyzer = AnalyzerName.EsMicrosoft
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
```

Comment: Woow, now all make sense! I will investigate more about stop words and other special kind of words in Azure Search. Thanks!